# 2 properties in transform in scss are giving me errors

Tags: sass

I encountered an error when working with my Angular project; I have a loop in scss:

```
@for $i from -3 through 3 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i + 4}) {
  }
}
```

And when I try to rotate the boxes and translate them Y with $i variable code:

```
@for $i from -3 through 3 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i + 4}) {
    transform: translateY(#{$i * -15}%) rotate(#{$i * 5}deg);
  }
}
```

I get an error:

> A two-dimensional transformation is applied to an element through the 'transform' property. This property contains a list of transform functions similar to those allowed by SVG.

I tried to put a static value of a translate and rotate and everything was fine

```
transform: translateY(-15%) rotate(5deg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the same error as your when trying your code on SassMeister, but the problem seems to come from the `%` unit. The problem is fixed when it's put inside the interpolation brackets:

```scss
translateY(#{$i * -15%})
```

You can also get the expected result by removing both unnecessary interpolations in the `transform` functions:

```scss
@for $i from -3 through 3 {
  &:nth-child(#{$i + 4}) {
    transform: translateY($i * -15%) rotate($i * 5deg);
  }
}
```